# Query including Importrange

Tags: select, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have one google spreadsheet, which is my source sheet. Now I have three more spreadsheets in which I want to pull information from the source sheet. To solve this I made use of the Query(Importrange) function. My problem is, that I only want to pull information, if a certain column in the source sheet is not blank.
To do so, my function looks like this:

```
=Query(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/....","Sheet name!range"),"SELECT Col.. WHERE Col..!=''")
```

As selected columns I chose all columns that I want to copy from the source sheet into the new one. The column behind WHERE is the column that is not allowed to be blank.

NOW there is the following problem: Some information is imported from the source sheet into the new one the right way, but others are not imported at all. Maybe because in the source Sheet there are some columns with dates, some with numbers, some with words.

I would be very happy if somebody could help me!
Thank you!

Comment: can you please share your complete function or the screenshots of the data and imported range so that a solution can be worked out

Comment: Can you share a copy of the sheets? What kind of information is not imported?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-FV_JgtBAhbzKqyon6q4T7mFYm5UDJCICXT_DK9Yt_M/edit?usp=sharing   this is the souce document, from where I want to export the information, where an SME number exist (yellow). It should be imported in https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BmI7H7F6yy76IDvJOh_3R6Z-2yDaZWSaNrfB0w8R7Vo/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

force it:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TO_TEXT(IMPORTRANGE("url", "sheet name!range")),
 "select Col.. 
  where Col.. is not null", 0)
```